# Cannot get uid from OpenAM after log in

Tags: java, tomcat, iis, openam

I setup a IIS server with OpenAM. Basically, when i request a url `http://ly.asto.asia/test`, it redirects to `http://oa.asto.asia:8787/openam` to login. After i login it redirects back to IIS server, but when i inspect in the request header, there's only `iplanetDirectory` in cookie, the `uid` is not included in request header.

In the OpenAM agent, i also add key maps in Agent/Application/ Profile Header and Response header.

Below are setting files of IIS Web Policy Agent.
`OpenSSOAgentBootstrap.properties`

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.naming.url = http://oa.asto.asia:8787/openam/namingservice 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.organization.name = /
com.sun.identity.agents.config.username = ly_agent
com.sun.identity.agents.config.password = XxBFeAmLHMdA5o3llkEp2A==
com.sun.identity.agents.config.key = wbp7crbzqt

com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.file = C:/web_agents/iis7_agent/Identifier_1/logs/debug/amAgent


com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.logfile = C:/web_agents/iis7_agent/Identifier_1/logs/audit/amAgent_ly_asto_asia.log


com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.level = 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.sslcert.dir = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.certdb.prefix = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.certdb.password = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.certificate.alias = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.trust.server.certs = true


com.sun.identity.agents.config.receive.timeout = 0
com.sun.identity.agents.config.connect.timeout = 0
com.sun.identity.agents.config.tcp.nodelay.enable = false


com.sun.identity.agents.config.forward.proxy.host = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.forward.proxy.port =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.forward.proxy.user =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.forward.proxy.password =

com.sun.identity.agents.config.profilename = ly_agent


com.forgerock.agents.ext.url.validation.level = 2
com.forgerock.agents.ext.url.validation.ping.interval = 60
com.forgerock.agents.ext.url.validation.ping.miss.count = 3
com.forgerock.agents.ext.url.validation.ping.ok.count = 3
com.forgerock.agents.ext.url.validation.default.url.set =  

ts.init.retry.max =
com.forgerock.agents.init.retry.wait =
# com.forgerock.agents.nss.shutdown = on
```

`OpenSSOAgentConfiguration.properties`

```
com.sun.identity.agents.config.login.url[0] = http://oa.asto.asia:8787/openam/UI/Login

com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.name = iPlanetDirectoryPro

com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.secure = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.level = 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.file.rotate = true
com.sun.identity.agents.config.debug.file.size = 10000000 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.audit.accesstype = LOG_NONE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.log.disposition = REMOTE
com.sun.identity.agents.config.remote.logfile = amAgent_ly_asto_asia.log
com.sun.identity.agents.config.remote.log.interval = 5
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.log.rotate = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.local.log.size = 52428800


com.sun.identity.agents.config.notification.enable = true
com.sun.identity.client.notification.url = http://ly.asto.asia:80/UpdateAgentCacheServlet?shortcircuit=false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.url.comparison.case.ignore = true

com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.cache.polling.interval = 3


com.sun.identity.agents.config.sso.cache.polling.interval = 3


com.sun.identity.agents.config.userid.param = UserToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.userid.param.type = SESSION


com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.fetch.mode = HTTP_HEADER


com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.mapping[uid] = uid

com.sun.identity.agents.config.session.attribute.fetch.mode = NONE

com.sun.identity.agents.config.session.attribute.mapping[] =


com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.fetch.mode = HTTP_HEADER


com.sun.identity.agents.config.response.attribute.mapping[uid] = uid


com.sun.identity.agents.config.attribute.multi.value.separator = |

com.sun.identity.agents.config.load.balancer.enable = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.agenturi.prefix = http://ly.asto.asia:80/amagent

com.sun.identity.agents.config.locale = en_US

com.sun.identity.agents.config.sso.only = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.access.denied.url =

com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.check.enable = true


com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.default = ly.asto.asia


com.sun.identity.agents.config.fqdn.mapping[] = 

com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset.enable = false


com.sun.identity.agents.config.cookie.reset[0] = 

com.sun.identity.agents.config.anonymous.user.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.anonymous.user.id = anonymous

com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url[0] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url.invert = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.url.attributes.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.notenforced.ip[0] =


com.sun.identity.agents.config.postdata.preserve.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.postcache.entry.lifetime = 10

com.sun.identity.agents.config.postdata.preserve.lbcookie =


com.sun.identity.agents.config.client.ip.validation.enable = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.cookie.prefix = HTTP_
com.sun.identity.agents.config.profile.attribute.cookie.maxage = 300


com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cdcservlet.url[0] = http://oa.asto.asia:8787/openam/cdcservlet
com.sun.identity.agents.config.cdsso.cookie.domain[0] = 

com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.url[0] = http://oa.asto.asia:8787/openam/UI/Logout
com.sun.identity.agents.config.agent.logout.url[0] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.cookie.reset[0] = 
com.sun.identity.agents.config.logout.redirect.url = 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.fetch.from.root.resource = true


com.sun.identity.agents.config.get.client.host.name = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.convert.mbyte.enable = false


com.sun.identity.agents.config.encode.url.special.chars.enable = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.encode.cookie.special.chars.enable = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.path.info = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.path.info.for.not.enforced.list = true

com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.protocol =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.host =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.port =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.override.notification.url =

com.sun.identity.agents.config.auth.connection.timeout =

com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.server.check = false

com.sun.identity.agents.config.poll.primary.server = 5

com.sun.identity.agents.config.ignore.preferred.naming.url = true

com.sun.identity.agents.config.polling.interval = 60

com.sun.identity.agents.config.cleanup.interval = 30

com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.auth.type = dsame 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.replaypasswd.key = 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.filter.priority = HIGH


com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.owa.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.owa.enable.change.protocol = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.iis.owa.enable.session.timeout.url = 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.proxy.override.host.port = false


com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.check.name.database = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.enable = false
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.cookie.name = LtpaToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.config.name = LtpaToken
com.sun.identity.agents.config.domino.ltpa.org.name = 


com.sun.identity.agents.config.policy.clock.skew = 0


com.sun.identity.agents.config.redirect.param = goto


com.sun.identity.agents.config.client.ip.header =
com.sun.identity.agents.config.client.hostname.header =
```

I really need your help. If you have any ideas, i'm very glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

how did you check request header? from browser plugin like 'Development Tool' in chrome? if so, you can not find that header since it is updated by the openam web agent. You can only get that header in IIS server side. In addition, how did you configure the agent key mapping? in my experience, I use cn=my-user-id, and I can get the header my-user-id with value 'the id of authenticated user' in my service provider side.

Comment: I've already solved this problem. But anyways, i have to use OpenAM to get the `uid` from OpenAM server.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the function to get `uid` from OpenAM server.

```
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
  String token = null;
  Cookie cookies[] = request.getCookies();
  if (cookies != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
      if (cookies[i].getName().equals("iPlanetDirectoryPro")) {
        token = cookies[i].getValue();
      }           
    }     
  }               
  String uid = null;
  String line = null;
  URL iurl = new URL("http://192.168.0.1:8080/openam/identity/attributes?subjectid=" + token);
  URLConnection connection = iurl.openConnection();
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( (InputStream) connection.getContent()));
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if ("userdetails.attribute.name=uid".equals(line)) {
      line = reader.readLine();
      uid = line.substring("userdetails.attribute.value=".length());
    }     
  }               
  return true;
}
```

Basically we can get `iPlanetDirectoryPro` token value from OpenAM request. After that we use `/openam/identity/attributes?subjectid=" + token` API to get the full user information.
Reference: http://tech-sketch.jp/2013/06/openam.html